# How do I switch to Software development job after having experience in Software Testing?

Tags: software-industry

I am Software Testing Engineer with 2.5 yrs of experience (both manual and automation testing.).

Companies are not considering my testing resume for the development vacancies.Please suggest me which skills should  i work on and which companies can give chance to sit for interview.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "companies are not considering my testing resume". This could mean, for example, you applied for a few positions and didn't hear back... (which means you may need resume work or simply applying to more places).

Answer (score 2):

Experience in automated testing is obviously your route to product development positions. I'd suggest looking for a position in an agile team where multi-disciplinary work is highly valued. (As distinct from agile teams where this is not so... )

Also - have a look at your resume, and consider re-writing it with an emphasis on your experience that is relevant for development work. At the top, you can put a summary paragraph that clearly states your intended career direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn the  current hot technologies in the market and practice them at home. e.g Java Basics , Advanced Java  Spring Hibernate Database (Oracle/MongodB) Webservers (tomcat/jboss) . For front ends jquery , angular , node.js

Look for a job near to entry position even if it means sacrificing some time/money ( salary wise )

Build something at home.

If you are database oriented , you can look up BI / ETL products e.g Informatica/Datastage etc.

Comment: NodeJS is not a front-end technology. jQuery is quite old and no longer recommended. Java has much more competition, and is declining, so that will be harder to squeeze in given experience. Employers can't expect much experience in ReactJS (very hot now) and deployment tech based on docker/rkt, so I would start there. It's a much more level playing field.

Comment: you are trying to tell a man to swim 100 laps when he has not even seen the swimming pool. I have told him the free style. Node.js is scripting language i agree.

Comment: We've had more success getting people up to speed on ReactJS than Java. Java is considerably more cumbersome than React, although they serve different purposes. Container stuff is more complex but less developer-y and in demand, and it has the same issues as a typical test setup, so it's an easier path. Btw, we use NodeJS for everything you'd normally use Java for, and the new ES6/7 stuff is fantastic.